# Client Credentials w/ Azure AD Token Validation

Tags: identityserver4

I am working on a mobile app that currently has the Intune SDK integrated app itself. This Intune SDK forces a user to log in using their company credentials and in response a subject ID and an Azure AD token is set in the app session.

I would like to integrate this app with an Identity Server instance using the client credentials grant, but in addition to the client id and password, I would like to pass along the Intune Azure AD token (and have it validated by the Identity Server) as a better level of security than the client secret (which is compromised by being in the app code).

What would be the best approach here?

Here are my thoughts on options:

- Create a custom grant type that accepts client id, client password and the Azure AD token? What's the best way to approach this, if so?
- Create an ISecretValidator implementation that checks if a password is an AAD token first, then validates the token if so. Does this introduce security concerns?

Comment: do you have some other apps authorized by your IdSrv? otherwise why need the IdSrv at all? next, for me it seems that Azure AD token alone is enough for authorization: it already has the client Id as a claim. so, again the simplest would be to use it directly as a bearer for your api...

Comment: @d_f we have services that require tokens issued by Identity Server. Other than Intune, we are not using Microsoft's identity. I am trying to accomplish what I outlined above because Intune/AAD is a valid authority and I don't want to make the user log in a second time via an interactive login flow.

Comment: then i prefer the custom grant approach. there is already the `PrivateKeyJwtSecretValidator` for validating jwts issued by the same IdSrv in the `validators` collection. to avoid *jwt hell* it would be better to handle the really custom case in the custom place. one more way is to introduce a custom api endpoint protected with the standard jwtBearerAuth handler, looking at MS authority for the keys. and then, inside the protected method you just issue a token you want, using idsrvTools.

Comment: @d_f so, for the `PrivateKeyJwtSecretValidator`, am I setting the secret of type `IdentityServerConstants.SecretTypes.X509CertificateBase64` as the signing key in AAD's signing materials?

Comment: I'm not sure I've caught the question, and I'm not really familiar with AAD, but if you are free to set your own signing materials there, then, yes, you should be able to use the same keys to make the handler thinking the token from AAD was signed locally. but I still don't like such a hacky approach :)